# How to update a React's state with a matrix

Tags: reactjs

I have the following for generating a table:

```
createTable = () => {
let table = [];
for (let i=0; i<this.state.rows; i++) {
  let rowID = `r${i}`;
  let cell = [];
  for (let j=0; j<this.state.cols; j++) {
    let cellID = `cell${i}-${j}`;
    cell.push(
      <td key={cellID} id={cellID}>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="number"
          name={`${i}-${j}`}
          id={`r${i}c${j}`}
          onChange={this.handleMatrixValuesChange}
          />
      </td>
    )
  }
  table.push(<tr key={i} id={rowID}>{cell}</tr>)
}

return table;
}
```

I'm using that to generate the table in the render:

```
<div>
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <table className="matrix">
      <tbody>
        {this.createTable()}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button
      type="submit">
      Generate
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

What I'm having a hard time with is how to store the input values from createTable() (using handleMatrixValuesChange() function, which is currently not doing anything) inside the state. Is that the recommended way of going about this? If so, how can I achieve this? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to achieve is you need to store values in a matrix.

In this solution i restructured the state to store it in a 2D array.

```
import React from "react";

const table = [
  [
    { id: 1, value: 1 },
    { id: 2, value: 2 },
    { id: 3, value: 3 },
    { id: 4, value: 4 }
  ],
  [
    { id: 5, value: 1 },
    { id: 6, value: 2 },
    { id: 7, value: 3 },
    { id: 8, value: 4 }
  ]
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(table);
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <table className="matrix">
          <tbody>
            {state.map((row) => (
              <tr>
                {row.map((column) => (
                  <td>
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      type="number"
                      name={column.id}
                      id={column.id}
                      value={column.value}
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(column.id, e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit">Generate</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );

  function onChange(id, val) {
    setState((prevState) =>
      prevState.map((row) =>
        row.map((col) => (col.id === id ? { ...col, value: val } : col))
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Using indices as identifier is not good when you're working on a dynamic table that's why I created an object to store the value and id.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this exact same problem before. All you need to do is call `this.forceUpdate()` every time you update the matrix if you are using a class-component. If you are using a functional component, you can create another state variable which you change when the matrix is changed. This will cause forceUpdate and will update your component correctly. By the way, this also works for any complex data types including classes.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Do you happen to have an example though of how you stored the `input` values for the rows and columns in your state?

Answer (score 0):

By declaring the method with arrow notation, `this` should work. Other option will be inject the function into `createTable` and get the ID to change the value on the state:

```
createTable = (handleMatrixValuesChange) => {
 ...
     <input
      className="form-control"
      type="number"
      name={`${i}-${j}`}
      id={`r${i}c${j}`}
      onChange={handleMatrixValuesChange}
      />
    </td>
    )
   }
   table.push(<tr key={i} id={rowID}>{cell}</tr>)
  }

  return table;
  }

  ...
  handleMatrixValuesChange = e => e.target.id
```